# How to handle mysql command-line password prompt using exec function

Tags: node.js

I don't know how id pipe the password variable in the exec function.
I've tried running it, but no prompt appears.

```
const {user,password,database}  = require('./config.js');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const comm = `mysql -u ${user} -p ${database} < ${QUERY_PATH} `
exec(comm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the only part missing is to use the callback, as recommended by Node in https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback .
Replace:

`exec(comm)`

by:

```
exec(comm, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(stdout);
})
```

This way, you need to type the password manually. If you don't want to type the password manually (**not recommended**, mySQL warns about safety concerns using this second method), then the code would be:

```
const comm = `mysql -u${user} -p${password} ${database} < ${QUERY_PATH}`
```

If you want to check what is the error happening to you, and that's how I debugged, use the callback function to log the errors:

```
exec(comm, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: The third one is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jgonzalez25 . If this answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks.